# why using multiple layer list to create a matrix of numpy has caused the 'list' type instead of directly '[]'?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

```
import re
import numpy as np

def readData(fname,datatype):
    c=re.compile(r'\s+')
    f=open(fname)
    rowstringlist=f.readlines()
    f.close()

    resultlist=[]
    for i in rowstringlist:
        i=i.strip()
        resultlist.append(map(float,re.split(c,i)))

    print resultlist
    data = np.matrix(resultlist)
    if datatype == 'X':
        data=np.matrix(np.insert(data,0,1,0))

    return data
```

and the result is as follows 
    `Out[45]: 
    matrix([[1, 1, 1],
            [list([1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]),
             list([2.0, 23.0, 43.0, 21.0, 32.0, 423.0]),
             list([124.0, 21.0, 2.0, 213.0, 2.0])]], dtype=object)`

Is it a bug or simply my default?
and when I just try separately which means that I just return the list and construct a matrix using the returned result, the result just works fine, so I am wondering what is the problem?

Comment: All the nested list must have the same length. Otherwise numpy can't infer the shape. Try it yourself: what would be the shape of your matrix?

Comment: Oh! This is just the problem, I haven't think about the problem, thank you very much! :)